# Exposing reactive observables in Swift framework

Tags: swift, frameworks, reactive-programming

I'm writing a framework in iOS Swift using RxSwift where kind of all tasks are handled through observables/subjects. Now, I'm wondering if an API handled in this way is advisable to be exposed with observables, forcing the enclosing app to use RxSwift, or to be wrapped by plain swift methods like, for instance, completion handlers.

Answer (score 0):

It is really up to you, but if you want to make sure all developers can use it, you should write it in plain Swift.

You can write `Rx` extensions in a separate framework.

It is quite elegant to do it via Cocoapods and subspecs.